# Spring validator never called

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, validation

I am trying to validate some information, so I added a validator and used @Valid in the parameter of the post method:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user.htm")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private IUserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String userInfo(Model model) {
       ....
        return "user";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String userInfoResult(@Valid @ModelAttribute UserForm userForm, BindingResult result, Model model ) {

        UserInfo stat = userService.getStatitisque(userForm.getSearchCritera());
        userForm.setListeExpediteur(listeExpediteur);

        userForm.setUserInfo(stat);
        model.addAttribute("userForm", userForm);
    }    
}

public class UserFormValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> type) {
        return UserForm.class.equals(type);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object o, Errors errors) {
        UserForm userForm = (User) o;
        ...
    }
}
```

When I debug, I never go in the UserFormValidator class.

Do I need to add something in these files?

- `web.xml`
- `applicationContext.xml`
- `dispatcher-servlet.xml`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the validator in an `@InitBinder` method:

```
@InitBinder(value="YourFormObjectName")
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(new FooValidator());
}
```

or globally via XML:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven validator="globalValidator"/>
```

**Reference:**

- [5.7.4.2 Configuring a Validator for
  use by Spring MVC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-mvc-configuring)

Comment: I find it so odd that Spring requires you to manually add each of your validator classes to each of your controllers when it does pretty much everything else automatically. Is there any reason for this particular choice of API?

Comment: @LordOfThePigs You don't have to add it manually - You can write something like "ValidatorAdvice" service, which will use ``@ControllerAdvice`` annotation. It will add Your validator to every Controller. Example:
``@ControllerAdvice
public class ValidatorAdvice {

    @Autowired
    protected LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator;

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.addValidators(new CollectionValidator(validator));
    }
}``

Comment: @thorinkor True, but this mechanism didn't exist at the time I wrote this answer

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd Oh, I was not aware of that, but it's worth mentioning anyway - people like me are still searching for answers :) One more important thing - ``@InitBinder`` should have specified ``value`` parameter - if You will not specify it, the validator will be used to every parameter :)

Answer (score 0):

5.7.4.3 Configuring a JSR-303 Validator for use by Spring MVC

> With JSR-303, a single javax.validation.Validator instance typically validates all model objects that declare validation constraints. To configure a JSR-303-backed Validator with Spring MVC, **simply add a JSR-303 Provider, such as Hibernate Validator, to your classpath**. Spring MVC will detect it and automatically enable JSR-303 support across all Controllers.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

> With this minimal configuration, anytime a @Valid @Controller input is encountered, it will be validated by the JSR-303 provider. JSR-303, in turn, will enforce any constraints declared against the input. Any ConstraintViolations will automatically be exposed as errors in the BindingResult renderable by standard Spring MVC form tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user.htm")
public class UserController {
@Autowired
private IUserService userService;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String userInfo(Model model) {
   ....
    return "user";
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String userInfoResult(Model model,
                             @Valid @ModelAttribute UserForm userForm,
                             BindingResult result) {
    /*
       add custom validation check to standard validation error
       (if not registry UserFormValidator in @InitBinder block)
    */
    new UserFormValidator().validate(userForm, error); 

    // check all validation errors   
    if (errors.hasErrors()) {
        // go back
        return userInfo(model);
    }

    ...
  } 
}
```

Comment: This is the third day but @InitBinder one is preferable among all possible ways to configure a custom Validator

Comment: Where does the `error` variable come from? How is it instantiated?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the validator in @InitBinder method

```
 @InitBinder
 protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
     binder.setValidator(new UserFormValidator ());
 }
```